# use a nodejs web server to serve a full rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

I and 4 colleagues will start on a university project and decided to use Ruby on Rails as it has many libraries that we need and is joyful.

The project is a website for researchers which will allow them to create account,login/logout,post their researches.

The project must feature hash tags and researches can be linked together, visitors must be able to search by tags and see the related researches, we may use a knowledge base to serve this knowledge to people.

So to my problem : performance, it is mentioned in the project paper that we should have good performance.

I've heard about Rails reputation of not having very good performance compared to others(Not sure if this has changed though but...).

I was thinking to use nodejs because it's very fast and scalable but unfortunately I didn't find all the libraries we need.

I searched and searched for a way to use a nodejs web server(expressjs or anything) only for serving and writing the whole application with Rails but I didn't find a way to execute ruby on nodejs.

So how to accomplish this ? If I use Nginx as a proxy server, can I then use nodejs as the main server(and If I can how?).

Thanks in advance.

### PS

Thought to mention that we'll use use the latest versions of Ruby,RoR.

As for Node.js we don't mind to use 5 or 4 as long as our goal is achieved.

Comment: If by university project you mean class project then I recommend you use RoR for reasons @kliakopo mentioned. But if performance is your primary concern from the start and/or you already know javascript well, then you might as well go with NodeJS. Rails is generally speaking faster to make something useful with than node. You cannot mix rails with nodejs at all.

Answer (score 4):

Scaling a web application is more about **good architecture** and **best practices** than it is about the web framework / language.

RoR has a bad reputation for performance coming from the early days when Twitter decided to switch to Scala. Actually they only switched some heavy duty processes for the back-end in Scala and take advantage of RoR's features for the rest.

Chances are that your application will not be scaling as much as Twitter. Even if you are going to, you should use an approach similar to theirs:

1. Make something that people will love using first. RoR helps you with fast prototyping.
2. If performance becomes an issue, then find the bottleneck. Chances are that RoR will not be the issue here. Most likely you need to improve something else, such as some Webserver configuration, or the Database needs indexes, or your server has too little resources.
3. If you reach a point that RoR IS actually the issue, you probably made something so valuable that the community of researchers will want to fix the issue for you...

Apart from Twitter, other large-scale sites that use RoR are Github, AirBnB, Basecamp, Hulu, Shopify and many more.

**Conclusion:** So my point is, RoR performs well enough that chances are that you don't need to be worrying about performance. Use it because it is fun to write and has the libraries you need, and worry about scaling when and IF it is needed.

Also, sorry to disappoint you, but running RoR on NodeJs is not possible, NodeJs is server-side Javascript, so it can't run Ruby. Alternatively you could run RoR on a JVM with JRuby but that is another story. If I were you I would stick to Ruby web servers like Passenger and Unicorn.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend you to use Nginx as a load balancer and for caching for your rails app, otherwise write your app in JavaScript, my hones opinion. NodeJS is a server side JavaScript and it's not possible to run ruby apps with node. 
Ruby is slower than NodeJS, just make a simple test with loops and strings, you'll see a major difference.

In Javascrip with 10 mio iterations you'll see results under a second and sometimes nearly a half a second.

```js
var str = 'blab lablaejd ksjdhsdlnsdsdksdkfnvdfvjeefvkdnfvkjfvidfvjndfvnfvfvovhelloasdkjfiweefsdffh';
    var newstring;
    var start, end,i;
    start = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    for(i = 0; i<10000000; i++) {
      var index = str.indexOf("hello");
      newstring = str.slice(index, index+5);
    }
    console.log(newstring);
    end = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    console.log(end-start);
    document.getElementById("str").innerHTML = newstring;
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML =  end-start;
```

```html
<p id="str"></p>
<p id="time"></p>
```

And now test the same code in ruby and you'll get something about 4 second.
[Ruby test code](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/14bf0/1)

The one of the advantages of NodeJS is the async, non-blocking code you can write.

But you have to decide, what you'll like coding with and have fun while doing so.

Comment: rubyfiddle seems to use old version of ruby(As it gives NoMethodError when trying to use Enumerator's methods), this with the fact that you can't compare languages like that makes your benchmark unfair

Comment: anyway in ruby iterators like "select,map,reduce,each" are much more preferable than ordinary for-loops and that's because they are much faster, you should write your ruby program with iterators and ruby 2.2.3

Comment: I don't think that this is an unfair benchmark, it's the most basic loop in each of those three languages. I've run every code on my machine with an i7 processor and all the same results, ruby always gets the last place, second python and on the first nodejs. I don't say that ruby is not good, but if speed is the question, nodeJS V8 engine is the better solution, in my honest opinion. And by the way, I've run the ruby code on ruby 1.9.3 and 2.2.3, no difference.

Comment: did you use ruby's iterators ? or just ordinary for-loop ? because ruby's iterators are much faster than the for-loop

Comment: Yes, with both versions, on my machine, where ruby and nodejs are compiled, ruby is slower. Everyone has his/her own preferences the way he/she likes to code and I don't know every code optimizing in ruby nor in js. One task can be coded in 100 different ways. If I'm wrong in any way, show me a better way to do it, and I'll gladly accept it. I always try to improve what I'm doing and share what works the best for me. If you have a snippet that's doing the same thing as the js version and beats it, I'd like to see where i'm doing it wrong in my ruby code, overall.